# Divide each element in a matrix by one element in R

Tags: r, division

Consider the following matrix:

```
matrix <- matrix(1:9, nrow = 3, ncol = 3)

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
```

For the two first columns (`[,1]` and `[,2]`), I want to divide each element until row `[3,]` with the number in row `[3,]`. That is, I want to get the following matrix:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  1/3  4/6 
[2,]  2/3  5/6
```

How do I do that in `R`?

Comment: Do you mean " with the number in *raw* [3,]" ? Column 3 is never used in you output, it's like you divide raw 1 and 2 bay raw 3

Comment: Your logic and end result do not align?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I have corrected the question now.

Comment: `m <- matrix(1:9, nrow = 3, ncol = 3);
sweep(m, 2, '/', STATS=m[3,])` or `sweep(m[-3,], 2, '/', STATS=m[3,])`

Comment: Try: `t(t(matrix[1:2,1:2]) / matrix[3,1:2])`

Comment: You can do `sweep(mat[1:2, ], 2, mat[3, ], "/")`.